# Auto-format/align arrays PhpStorm

Tags: php, arrays, phpstorm

I am using Ubuntu.

How can I tell PhpStorm 2017.3 to keep the following array as it is when clicking <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + L</kbd> to reformat my code:

```
<?php
return [

'page_not_found' => 'Page not Found',
'message_required' => 'Please enter your message',
];
```

to this

```
<?php
return [

'page_not_found'   => 'Page not Found',
'message_required' => 'Please enter your message',
];
```

Comment: try to write in standard code styles. Use PSR-2

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Answer (score 10):

Currently I am answering with respect to PHP settings (it's similar for other languages.)

1) Open PHP Storm

2) Goto settings

3) Find `editor tab` > `Code style` > `PHP`

4) Now you will find the option `"Wrapping and braces"` (3rd tab)

5) Now within that tab last 3rd option you will find  `Array Initializer` (select the first 2 options. checkout screenshot)

[image: screenshot]